# How to show trend/DRIFT from two tide gauge sensor that show big difference on highest and lowest tide range

Tags: matlab, time-series, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, timeserieschart

I have collected two month data set showing water level from two different sensor installed on the **same location** with the **same datum/reference position**. 
[Simultaneously plot from both sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNmGs.jpg) 
they should give same value because they were read the same at first time  but unfortunately they deviate at maximum and minimum tidal range. 
[when you zoom at maximum range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBk6W.jpg)
Am try to prove one of the sensor is DRIFT away from the other, is the any ways to do this. using matlab

so far i have done this

```
%% PLOT OF MEAN SEA LEVEL 
%mean sea level in every 12:24.5 Hrs
clc
n = 74; % dataset where in every 10 minutes 74 gives 1-period of tide
a1c = reshape(cumsum(wl1c,2),[],1); % wl1c = 8280x1 matrix of value of waterlevel 1
mwl1c = arrayfun(@(i) mean(a1c(i:i+n-1)),1:n:length(a1c)-n+1)'; % the averaged vector
a2c = reshape(cumsum(wl2c,2),[],1); %  wl2c = 8280x1 matrix of value of waterlevel 2
mwl2c = arrayfun(@(i) mean(a2c(i:i+n-1)),1:n:length(a2c)-n+1)'; % the averaged vector
scatter((1:length(mwl1c))',mwl1c,10);
lsline;
hold on;
scatter((1:length(mwl2c))',mwl2c,10);
lsline;
hold off
```

this give me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Tqv.png)

and

```
%% Plot mean sea level 
% %mean sea level in every 24 Hrs
clc
n2 = (148); % dataset where in every 10 minutes 
a1c = reshape(cumsum(wl1c,2),[],1); % wl1c = 8280x1 matrix of value of waterlevel 1
mwl1c = arrayfun(@(i) mean(a1c(i:i+n2-1)),1:n2:length(a1c)-n2+1)'; % the averaged vector
a2c = reshape(cumsum(wl2c,2),[],1); %  wl2c = 8280x1 matrix of value of waterlevel 2
mwl2c = arrayfun(@(i) mean(a2c(i:i+n2-1)),1:n2:length(a2c)-n2+1)'; % the averaged vector
scatter((1:length(mwl1c))',mwl1c,10);
lsline;
hold on;
scatter((1:length(mwl2c))',mwl2c,10);
lsline;
```

give me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqyht.png)

i also do commulative

```
%% PLOT ALL DATA IN CUMMULATIVE SUM
clc
cs1c=cumsum(wl1c);                      %wl1c=waterlevel 1
cs2c=cumsum(wl2c);                      %wl2c=waterlevel 2
plot(tc,cs1c); hold on; plot(tc,cs2c);hold off;
```

show i bit of difference between this two sensor, i was asking more others method of showing the trend between this two sensor.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us some code?

Comment: i have edit my question @mbuechmann

Comment: I would plot the difference of the 2 datasets vs time you show in `Simultaneously plot from both sensor`.
This way we can see if there is an offset or a linearity difference between the 2 sensors.
Also it would be interesting to have a look at the data sheet of the sensors and see if there are correction factors given in it.

Comment: thank you @vrleboss i plot them on same plot they only show non linear difference on crest and trough although if use `lsline` the diviation increase as time increase. is the any more proof i can use to show they difference.?